# Color Math and Programming

Tags: node.js, colors, rgb, cielab

I am currently trying to build a program that will accept a image and replace all of its individual parts **20x20** with individual images (up to a 1000) that are a best visual match.

I researched and learned about avg RGB/Color, my broad idea of how I would build the program is that I first calculate the average `Color/RGB` transform the `RGB` to `CIE-L*ab` and select the image (up to a 1000) that has the smallest difference to a **20x20** pixel of the input image.

I am not asking for code, just some resources that can better help me understand how I get the transformation from `RGB` to `CIE-L*ab` 1976 Comparison.

I am not interested in Euclidian distance to calculate the distances because it does not take human color perception into account. If it helps, i'm building the program in `NodeJS`

Thank You

Comment: I think https://github.com/toish/chromatism may be helpful to you.

Comment: @user3351605 Thanks, looks very helpful. I will make sure to take a look!

Comment: if that library ends up working well for your needs, consider creating a self-answer that explains how you were able to use it to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I managed to do it was using two node modules, `image-average-color` and `color-space`. I first calculated the average color of each image in the collection, converted it to `CIE-L*ab` and stored it in an array.

I then extracted each *20x20* block of the input image, calculated the `CIE-L*ab` aswell and found the smallest distance in the array to the *20x20* block